# Doesn't get a form in CenterScreen programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get a form in a center screen programmatically.
in the codes of Else part is executing perfectly.

```
    Dim X%, Y%
    Call FrmCommonCodes.FormLocationXYValues(X, Y)
    If X = 100 And Y = 100 Then
        'Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.StartPosition = Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Else
        Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(X, Y)
    End If

    ''FrmCommonCodes.FormLocationXYValues()

    Public Sub FormLocationXYValues(ByRef X As Double, ByRef Y As Double)
    Using MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = GetConnection(), MyCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM options", MyConnection)
        If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConnection.Open()
        Using MyDataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader
            While MyDataReader.Read
                X = MyDataReader("formlocation_x")
                Y = MyDataReader("formlocation_y")
                Return
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: You know there's a property on the form you can just set that will do this, right? Also, **never** use the `Call` keyword in VB.Net. It's only there for compatibility when migrating old code from vb6.

Comment: Setting the `StartPosition` of a form that is already loaded isn't going to do much.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , Justin Ryan .... No way via codes? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, what you should do is set the `StartPosition` property for the form to `CenterScreen` in the designer. Then if the X and Y coordinates match your default the Form will already be in the right place. That will simplify the code, and fix the problem where setting a start position for a form has no effect if the form has already started:

```
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
Call FrmCommonCodes.FormLocationXYValues(X, Y)
If X <> 100 OrElse Y <> 100 Then
    'Default is "CenterScreen", if this code does not run
    Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(X, Y)
End If
```

Additionally, you may want to move this code to the Form's constructor, or at least a method that be called *before* the form is shown. Otherwise, you can see form load up CenterScreen and then jump to the desired location afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Just one line :

```
Me.CenterToScreen()
```